# Join two temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to join two temp tables.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #Result ( Process varchar(50), SuccessCount int, FailureCount int)
CREATE TABLE #SuccessResult ( Process varchar(50), SuccessCount int)
CREATE TABLE #FailureResult ( Process varchar(50), FailureCount int)
```

I have some data in my tables, and here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO #Result (Process, SuccessCount, FailureCount)
SELECT s.Process,s.SuccessCount,f.FailureCount
FROM #SuccessResult s, #FailureResult as f
INNER JOIN #SuccessResult on f.Process = #SuccessResult.Process
```

I'm getting this error:

> The multi-part identifier f.Process could not be found

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't get an error: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7646

Comment: I don't get an error either. However, you join itself is a little odd, as many others have noted.

Comment: We should get another 20 users to post identical answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO #Result (Process, SuccessCount, FailureCount)
SELECT s.Process,s.SuccessCount,f.FailureCount
FROM #SuccessResult s 
INNER JOIN #FailureResult f on f.Process = #SuccessResult.Process
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the right syntax for `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO #Result (Process, SuccessCount, FailureCount)
SELECT s.Process, s.SuccessCount, f.FailureCount
FROM #FailureResult as f
INNER JOIN #SuccessResult s on f.Process = s.Process
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the implicit join.

```
INSERT INTO #Result (Process, SuccessCount, FailureCount)
SELECT s.Process,s.SuccessCount,f.FailureCount
FROM #SuccessResult s
INNER JOIN #FailureResult f on f.Process = s.Process
```